# Square made up with polyominoes

Tags: no-computers, polyomino

[image]

A 3 x 6 rectangle has 2 holes in it as shown. Can you cut it into 3 polyominoes with different areas so that they can form a square? The pieces can’t be flipped when they form the square and two solutions are the same if they are identical after rotation and/or reflection.

Comment: If diagonal cuts are allowed, are they really polyominoes?

Comment: Oh sorry, you can’t make diagonal cuts. @Randal'Thor

Comment: Yes you’re right @hexomino

Comment: You say "a rectangle has 2 holes". Is that the statement of the problem, and the picture is just one possible example? Or is the picture the only one you're asking about?

Comment: If we can't flip pieces, how do we get reflections?

Comment: @msh210 1. Yes  2. There could be more than one solution. I mean that two solutions are idem if they are the same after rotations or reflections.

Comment: Nice puzzle. I counted the solutions with a program, all I'll say is you should be able to find them all by hand in reasonable time and if you relax the 'no flipping' constraint, there aren't many more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this one, you don't even need to rotate the pieces:

> [image]
>
>  Text version:
>  `rrbggg`
>  `r br g`
>  `rrrrgg`
>  becomes
>  `gggb`
>  `rrgb`
>  `rggr`
>  `rrrr`

And the final ones, which are closely related:

> [image]    [image]
>
>  Text version:
>  `ggggbb    ggggbb`
>  `g gg b    g gg b`
>  `grgbbb    rrgbbb`
>  becomes
>  `gggg      gggg`
>  `gbgg      gbgg`
>  `gbgb      rbgb`
>  `rbbb      rbbb`

Comment: Nice! There is one left.

Comment: @Displaymaths found it! Nice puzzle!

Comment: Oh sorry, there is a last one.

Comment: Oh, of course, it's a small variation. I'll add it in a few minutes.

Comment: There are only two more if you allow flipping, if you want to get those as well since you are on a roll...

Answer (score 7):

Here's one solution:

> [image]

Other solutions may be possible.

Comment: True, there are more.